# How to append a text field in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

For instance using textField.setText it replaces the text currently in the text field however I want the output to go one step down from the previous output. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `textField.setText(textField.getText() + textToAppend)` - although, it would be more efficient to add the text directly to the `Document`

Comment: Please provide us with the code you've written so far.

Comment: you might want to add a newline char in there somewhere (i.e. `\n`)

Comment: Don't use textField.setText( textField.getText() + "...."). That is not the way to append text. This will generate incorrect events since you will get an event for all the deleted text and then another event for all  the added text which is wrong. Reread my answer, I provided the code for the JTextArea.append(...) method.

Comment: (1-) Why did you even ask this question? In the code you posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293883/why-does-the-jframe-freeze-when-you-press-enter-in-the-jtextfield, you are using a `JTextArea`. a `JTextArea` supports an `append(...)` method. Ask a question about the proper component. We can't guess what you are really thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the text directly to the `Document`:

```
Document doc = textField.getDocument();
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "the text", null);
```

Another option might be to use:

```
textField.replaceSelection(...);
```

and the text will be added at the current caret position.

Edit:

Here is the code used by the `append(...)` method of a `JTextArea`

```
public void append(String str) {
    Document doc = getDocument();
    if (doc != null) {
        try {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), str, null);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you could use the `replaceSelection(...)` method since there in not need for the try/catch block.